# Excel - how to call function that uses calling rows number in the formula

Tags: excel

Is there a way in excel to define a formula that uses whatever row number is calling the formula and then return the value to that cell? I'm currently in a purgatory of long IFS statement to perform the data transformation. I have a spreadsheet that has data related to electronic parts. In order to import this data into another program certain fields/names have to exactly match the program that is importing the data. For example, the program I need to import to may have a part type name "capacitor" and subtype "electrolytic 10-100uF" and my current spreadsheet has a field part type name "cap" and subtype "aluminum electrolytic" and maybe another field in the spreadsheet that has the value of "50uF". So my IFS statement has logic to check each of the three fields in my spreadsheet and then rename a couple of new columns I created for name and subtype to match what the importing program needs. My IFS statements are getting huge because I need logic for all the part types and where to look in the other columns to create the matching categories/names.

I was hoping to create a formula for each category type such as for a capacitor to go and look at the name, subtype, and value fields in my spreadsheet and then create the correct matching name and subtype fields for the new program. I would then create a new formula for each part as the data needed may vary so the formulas would vary based on part type. I was hoping this would be a more clean/organized approach that would make it more readable for others. In theory my new cell calculation would just be a short IFS statement that checks for part type and then calls the relevant function. Any ideas? I need something simple within excel as don't have experience programming VBA or macros.

Here is an example of my current approach where the IFS statement is getting huge and unreadable:

```
=IFS(AND(M3="Capacitor", N3="General"),"Fixed, Ceramic",N3="PWB","Printed Board, Edge",N3="Fixed Tantalum", "Tantalum, Solid, Hermetic",N3="Fixed Discrete", "Film, <=1Megohm",N3="General Purpose Diode", "Silicon, General, <=20A",N3="Opto-Electronic Devices","LED",M3="Filter","RF/Microwave Passive, filter",N3="Field Effect Transistor","Field Effect, Si, Switch",N3="General Purpose Transistor","Silicon, NPN, 0.6-6.0W", N3="Coil","Coil, Load",N3="Transformer","Transformer, Radio",N3="Network","Thick or Thin Film",TRUE,N3)
```

Comment: This sounds like you need a lookup table maybe?